I am unable to add my django project to a github repository due to a loop of errors
I am trying to connect my Django project to a Git repository but whenever I try to stage, commit, then push I get an error when I push about how "The branch "main" has no remote branch. Would you like to publish this branch?" I click okay then it says "Can't push refs to remote, Try running "Pull" first to integrate your changes." but when I pull I get the following error "Git: There is no tracking information for the current branch" so I am completely lost and I am unsure as to what else to provide for this problem to be fixed since this is also my first time doing a solo coding project.
I have tried looking up what to do but whenever I do its nothing that helps with the current situation because its a whole loop of me not knowing what the cause is and where to start looking.

what does git remote shows?

I suspect you don't have a an upstream remote set for for the main branch.
To set your github repository as the remote branch, execute the following:
git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>

Replace <remote_name> with what you want to name the remote (defaults to origin)
Replace <remote_url> with a github link, (eg. https://github.com/django/django.git)
If this doesn't work, please update your question with the output of:
git remote -v


The error you are encountering may be due to some conflicts in your current branch. You can resolve this by using these set of steps:
Take a pull from current branch

Then resolve the conflicts

```git add .
```git commit -m "msg"

Again take a pull and make your you are already up to date

```git push origin current-branch-name

Hope this works.



Take a pull from current branch -- but he already said he can't do that.  This answer is not helpful.
